# SQL table creation to save distance between multiple points

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on a project where I have to save distance between points, I have an api to get the distance between points but the problem is how to save them in MySql. Like if I have 3 points then I have to save the distance  of each point from rest all points into the database.

For this I could have simply make a table of n column and n rows and save the distance like this :

```
| | a | b | c |
---------------
|a| 0 | 6 | 8 |  
|b| 6 | 0 | 5 |
|c| 8 | 5 | 0 |
```

but the problem is my number of points will also increase in future, in that case I will have to add extra column also which is not a good practice.

Any good approach for this ?

Comment: Does it have to be mysql? you could probably do it easier using a graph database. If you are required to do it in mysql, you can use a field for the current node and a field with a json array of all the other nodes.

Comment: Since you are getting the points from api, you can use directly inserto into table.

Comment: Create 2 tables , 1 for parent like point 1 and 2nd table for distance with 4 cols 1st col will hold the reference of parent table 2nd will save start point 3rd col will save end point and 4th to save the distance between these two points, so lets say you have 3 points data so in distance table there will 3 entries that will hold distance between these points, AB,AC & BC and same logic will follow for different no. of points

Comment: That one helped @MKhalidJunaid

Answer (score 1):

Store as points in a [Cartesian space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), either (x,y) if two dimensions or (x,y,z) if three dimensions. Then you can create an easy algorithm to calculate the distance array when needed. So table structure becomes:

Point label

x coordinate

y coordinate

This will be fully scalable and very flexible. For instance you could calculate distance from point a to z via b.